# Is it possible to integrate with complex bounds?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to integrate $e^{-z^2}$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ along the curve $z(t)=Re^{it}, \, t\in[0,\pi/4]$ where $R$ is the radius of the circle. I am given that I can interpret $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ as $\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{0}^{R}$ and I have that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz=\sqrt{\pi}$.

**I want to show $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-(Re^{it})^2}Rie^{it}dt=0$.**

What I've done so far:

Approach 1:

$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-(Re^{it})^2}Rie^{it}dt$. By u-sub, $u=Re^{it}, du=Rie^{it}dt$ I have $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{R}^{R\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)}e^{-u^2}du$. If I throw bars on everything, I get $$\left\vert\int_\gamma f(z)dz\right\vert=\left\vert\int_{R}^{R\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)}e^{-u^2}du\right\vert\leq \left\vert\int_{0}^{R\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)}e^{-u^2}du\right\vert
\leq \left\vert 1-e^{-(R\sqrt{2}/2+iR\sqrt{2}/2)^2}\right\vert\leq 1-e^{-iR^2}$$.

I want to take the limit as $R\to \infty$ but I can't make sense of what $e^{-iR^2}$ is.

Approach 2: $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}Rie^{-(Re^{it})^2}e^{it}dt=Ri\int_{0}^{\pi/4}e^{-(R^2)(\cos^2(t)-\sin^{2}(t)+2i\sin(t)\cos(t))}e^{it}dt$.

But again, I have an imaginary power of $e$. Could I say that $|(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))^2|\leq 2$?

Comment: It is fine to integrate along paths with complex ends. But the absolute value cannot produce non-real numbers, so your last inequality is wrong. How did you come up with it? If $t$ is real then $|\cos(t)+i\sin(t)|=1$, but I do not see how that helps.

Comment: @Conifold, I was going to use that to bound the exponent in the second approach. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral gives an approach to this question I ask but with a different parameter. I'm trying to do it my own way and not copy.